# Created a splash screen by appending a div with jQuery, but

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I made a splash page using jQuery by appending a div on the page load.  After a set amount of time, the body of the page fades in, though the appended div still displays itself at the end of the page.  Tried to add .remove() at the end of the function to see if that would help, nothing though. I'd like to have it disappear as the rest of the page loads.  Let me know if i'm going about this the wrong way.

https://swaybs.github.io/jdphotography/

```
      $(document).ready(function() {


    $('html').append('<h1 class="onLoad">loading...</h1>');


    /*! Fades in page on load */
    $('body').css('display', 'none');
    $('body').delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
    $('html').remove('.onload');
```

Comment: Typo.  You gave it class `onLoad`, but are trying to remove `.onload`

Comment: There are various issues with this question that are making it too broad.  #1) `delay()` is intended to be used with animations, and **is not** a replacement for `setTimeout()`.  This is expressly stated in the api (Ref. http://api.jquery.com/delay/ 
 first yellow block) and `css()` is not an animation based method, so the delay will do nothing.  #2) The typo in the class name in the remove.  #3) The remove needs to be a part of the callback of the fadeIn so that it only happens when the fadeIn finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `complete` callback function of [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/#fadeIn-duration-complete) to remove (or fade out the loading message).

**Note:** Instead of hiding the `body`, and adding the `h1` to the `html`, it's better to add a use a main element (`div` or `main`), you can hide/show.

```js
$('html')
  .append('<h1 class="onLoad">loading...</h1>');
  
$('body').css('display', 'none')
.delay(4000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
  $('.onLoad').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

I'm part of the body
```

Comment: Thanks man!  That seemed to do it for me.  I'm still new to Javascript, so thanks for bearing with me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on the CSS. The loading div should have an absolute positioning (and its container should have a relative one), otherwise it will always be pushed down by other elements as they appear.